# Running GoodData without internet connection

Tags: gooddata

I was trying to run GD.CN on premise without internet connection, but I wasn't successful. Is it even possible? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GoodData.CN can run on air-gapped environments. You need to preload all required docker images (both gooddata and 3rd party) to your private docker registry and deploy helm chart pointing configuration to this private registry. [Here](https://www.gooddata.com/developers/cloud-native/doc/1.3/installation/k8s/helm-chart-installation/#pull-application-images-to-your-registry-air-gapped-installations-only) you can find more details.